# add a css class to last row and remove button only from last row in slickgrid

Tags: slickgrid

I am using slickgrid which contains around 13 columnsand displays data in the form of heirarchy. I have inserted a button which will appear on third column of all rows. On that button click, i am trying to open a popup. I was trying to add a css class for last row of the slickgrid to make the row non-editable. Also i want to remove that button from the last row.
I have used below code to remove button.

```
 $($('.grid-canvas').children()[data.len-1].children[3]).context.previousSibling. innerHTML = "";
```

But when toggle button is clicked, that button appears in the last row and the row goes into edit mode. Can anyone please help me resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `getItemMetaData` api and add it as a function to your data object (either the array of data rows or the dataView, if you're using `slick.dataview.js`)

```
data.getItemMetaData = function(row){
   if(row == data.length - 1){
       return { cssClasses: 'disable-edits' };
   }
   return {};
}
```

See some [examples](https://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid/wiki/Examples) and look into [the datview object](https://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid/wiki/DataView).